# Saving lambda expression or function to a binary file

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Basically, I have a function which takes some arguments, one of which is a lambda expression or function:

`foo(int i, int j, std::function<double(double)> func);`

I'd like to be able to save these arguments to a binary file, so something like this:

```
std::ofstream os("test.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&i), std::streamsize(sizeof(int)));
os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&j), std::streamsize(sizeof(int)));
// What to do for func?
```

Is there a way to do this? This `save` function would be called before `foo`, so I'd know whether or not the input is an actual function or lambda (if that helps). It doesn't need to be portable between systems- I'd just like to be able to save these arguments to disk so I can load them up and rerun the function using the same parameters later.

Comment: Replace the lambdas by functors: structs with an operator `T operator () ()`

Comment: What are the operations in that function object?  Is later a different execution of the program?  Have you looked at boost phoenix?  Is the function guaranteed to be pure?  Of restricted impurity?

Answer (score 0):

I think saving lamda functions directly to disk is not possible. You can however implement a data structure to Register your function first and then save a reference to the structure to disk. This could look something like this:

```
std::map<std::string,std::function<double(double)> > functions;
```

When the program starts you Register the functions like this:

```
...
functions["func1"] = ...
functions["func2"] = ...
...
```

Then you change foo like this:

```
foo(int i, int j, std::string func)
{
    //Save i, j and func
    //func can be saved to disk because it is a std::string
}
```

Then you can call the desired function like this:

```
double val = 1.0;
double res = functions[func](val);
```

The only problem with this approach is that you need to register all possible functions.